# Replacing a delimiter symbol in a field

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a csv in where fields are delimited by `|`.

```
|time: 10:19 | Error: File not found| Condition: None | path: some 

|time: 10:20 | Error: File not found| Condition: a|b | path: some
```

The delimiter `|` will sometimes appear in the 4th field (the `Condition` field). I want to replace this `|` with `OR` like:

`Condition: a|b` Will become:  `Condition: a OR b`

How can I use sed or awk for this?

Comment: What is the separator between `Condition:` and `a|b`? Spaces? Tabs?

Comment: They all are spaces. No tabs.

Comment: Does your file have blank lines in it?

Comment: You should really fix the process that creates that "csv" file so that proper field quoting is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' 'NF == 6 {$4 = $4 " OR " $5; $5=$6; NF--} 1' file
```

This just works with the number of pipe-separated fields. You expect there to be 5 but if there is one extra, join with the desired string.

Or, GNU sed:

```
sed 's/|/|/5; ta; n; :a; s/|/ OR /4' file
```

If there are 5 pipes, change the 4th one. Does not work with the default sed on MacOS --
 if the semicolons are replaced by newlines, MacOS sed is OK with these commands (it seems the label name must be followed by a newline with the BSD-derived sed).

---

What if there are *more* than 1 extra pipe? Consider this file:

```
|time: 10:19 | Error: File not found| Condition: None | path: some
|time: 10:20 | Error: File not found| Condition: a|b | path: someh
|time: 12:34 | NO ERROR | Condition: a|b AND c|d AND e|f | path: nil
```

Extending the sed solution is straightforward: add a "jump-if"

```
sed ':b; s/|/|/5; ta; n; :a; s/|/ OR /4; tb' file
```

The awk gets a bit wordier:

```
awk -F'|' -v O FS='|' '{
    while (NF > 5) {
        $4 = $4 " OR " $5
        for (i = 5; i < NF; i++)
            $i = $(i+1)
        NF--
    }
    print
}' file
```

Comment: Nice one!  I was trying to figure out how to get rid of the extra field.

Comment: I vaguely recall being told that manipulating NF doesn't always work, but that program worked correctly on gawk, mawk and plain awk.

Comment: How on earth were you able to come up with such a thorough answer using various commands in less than 20 minutes?  Sweet!

Comment: I too am a very stable genius ;)

Comment: Glenn - per POSIX incrementing NF adds a blank field. Decrementing NF is the one that's undefined behavior and so wont do what you want in some awks, e.g. OSX/BSD awk. I'm just struggling to be stable...

Comment: I recently got a macbook for work, and this code did give the right results. One could write this, to avoid manipulating NF: `awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' 'NF == 6 {$0 = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 " OR " $5 FS $6} 1'`

Answer (score 1):

Give a test to this:

```
sed 's/Condition:[ ]*\([a-zA-Z]*\)|\([a-zA-Z]*\)/Condition: \1 OR \2/g' your_file
```

Assuming `a` and `b` are alphabetic.

Comment: This is almost what I wanted. Is it possible to generalize this for all characters, alpha/numeric/symbols. For ex:                                                                                     echo "|time: 10:20 | Error: File not found| Condition: %500  a|b | path: some" | sed 's/Condition:[ ]*\([a-zA-Z]*\)|\([a-zA-Z]*\)/Condition: \1 OR \2/g'                                   Between "Condition" and "|" there can be [a-z][0-9] or "." or "%" or ":"

Comment: Yes it is, it's all about regular expressions, according to what type of text you want to extend. But check @glenn jackman's solution, it seems more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 Script. Breaks the csv file into a list defined by delimiter '|' and then join the fields if there's an extra one and it starts with the word "Condition:"

```
import csv

for line in list(csv.reader(open('filename', 'r'), delimiter='|')):
    if len(line) > 5 and line[3].lstrip().startswith('Condition:'):
        print('|'.join(line[:3] + [line[3] + ' OR ' + line[4]]+line[5:]))
    else:
        print('|'.join(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU sed` you can do it as shown:

```
 $ sed -e '
   s/|/\n/4g
   s/\(.*\)\n/\1|/
   s/\n/ OR /g
 ' inp


 $ perl -lpe '1 while s/Condition:.*\K\|(?! path:)/ OR /' inp


 $ perl -lpe '
   /Condition:.*?(?=\|)/g;
   s/\G.(.*?)(?=\|)/ OR $1/g;
 ' inp

$ perl -F'[|]' -pale '
     $_ = join "|", @F[0..2], join(" OR ", @F[3..$#F-1]), $F[-1] if @F > 5;
 ' inp

 $ perl -lpe '
     my($dlim, $pos_f3, $pos_f4, $knt) = qw/|/;
     $pos_f3 = 1+index($_,$dlim,$pos_f3) while ++$knt < 4;
     $pos_f4 = rindex($_,$dlim);
     s/\Q$dlim\E/ OR /g for substr $_, $pos_f3, $pos_f4-$pos_f3;
 ' inp
```

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to modifying a target field that can contain separators is:

```
/(match the fields before the target)(.*)(match the fields after the target)/ {
   modify the target which is the middle section, the string matching the ".*"
}
```

e.g. with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk '
    match($0,/(([^|]*[|]){3})(.*)([|][^|]*)/,a) {
        gsub(/[|]/," OR ",a[3])
        $0 = a[1] a[3] a[4]
    }
1' file
|time: 10:19 | Error: File not found| Condition: None | path: some
|time: 10:20 | Error: File not found| Condition: a OR b | path: some
```

and given the more interesting input shown in Glenn's answer:

```
$ cat file
|time: 10:19 | Error: File not found| Condition: None | path: some
|time: 10:20 | Error: File not found| Condition: a|b | path: someh
|time: 12:34 | NO ERROR | Condition: a|b AND c|d AND e|f | path: nil

$ awk '
    match($0,/(([^|]*[|]){3})(.*)([|][^|]*)/,a) {
        gsub(/[|]/," OR ",a[3])
        $0 = a[1] a[3] a[4]
    }
1' file
|time: 10:19 | Error: File not found| Condition: None | path: some
|time: 10:20 | Error: File not found| Condition: a OR b | path: someh
|time: 12:34 | NO ERROR | Condition: a OR b AND c OR d AND e OR f | path: nil
```

With any awk it'd be:

```
$ awk '
    match($0,/(([^|]*[|]){3})/) {
        a[1] = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        rest = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        match(rest,/[|][^|]*$/)
        a[3] = substr(rest,1,RSTART-1)
        a[4] = substr(rest,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        gsub(/[|]/," OR ",a[3])
        $0 = a[1] a[3] a[4]
    }
1' file
|time: 10:19 | Error: File not found| Condition: None | path: some
|time: 10:20 | Error: File not found| Condition: a OR b | path: someh
|time: 12:34 | NO ERROR | Condition: a OR b AND c OR d AND e OR f | path: nil
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code sample the defining rule appears to be that wherever `|` is **not** bounded on both sides by a space then you want if to become `OR`, so simply

```
sed -E 's/([^ ])\|([^ ])/\1 OR \2/g' test
```